# Cutting diagonal movement from pan gesture

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to lock my image I'm dragging (objectDragging) to the x or y center, depending which way I'm moving or influencing it to move. If I'm influencing it to the right, I want it to lock on its initial Y position, and only allow it to go right (or back left, on a straight line). If I'm influencing it upward, lock its x position and allow it to move straight up or down on the exact line. I'm using a switch for my movement handling, with lots of code in the .end case, so I didn't want to include a lot of code. Just hoping for an idea — wasn't able to find a lot.

```
    switch(recognizer.state) {

    objectDragging = (recognizer.view?.tag)!

    case .began:

        initPosx = Int(recognizer.view!.center.x)
        initPosy = Int(recognizer.view!.center.y)
    case .changed:
        ...
```

Comment: You haven't made it clear what you want to do. Do you want to be able to automatically decide if the user is doing a mostly-up-and-down gesture or a mostly-side-to-side gesture, and then lock the movement to that dimension? Or is there some other factor that decides if the user is moving the object side-to-side or up-and-down?

Comment: Sorry, my post was a little vague. All my images are UserInteractionEnabled and move wherever you drag them to. I want to determine which way the user is beginning to drag them, and then lock it into a straight line in that direction, or on that plane. Similar to moving collection view cells around.

Comment: You can try checking the initial `velocity` and decide if it a mostly horizontal or mostly vertical pan and then set a flag so that you can ignore one of the axes in future pan events.

Comment: Velocity is seeming to help me get the information. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After the suggestion of using `velocity` from `Paulw11` I've had success limiting the direction of the image I'm moving by deciding which way we are initially moving the image (in .began) and then locking the x or y (in .changed). Incase anyone comes across this with a similar issue, heres the gist of my solution that is working well for my application:

```
switch(recognizer.state) {
case .began:
let velocity = recognizer.velocity(in: self.view)
if (velocity.x > velocity.y) && (velocity.x > 0) {
            print("moving right")
            myBlocks[objectDragging].center.y = CGFloat(initPosy)
            movingRight = true
        }
        else if ((abs(velocity.x)) > velocity.y) && (velocity.x < 0) {
            print("moving left")
            myBlocks[objectDragging].center.y = CGFloat(initPosy)
            movingLeft = true
        }
        else if (velocity.y > velocity.x) && (velocity.y > 0) {
            print("moving down")
            myBlocks[objectDragging].center.x = CGFloat(initPosx)
            movingDown = true
        }
        else if ((abs(velocity.y)) > velocity.x) && (velocity.y < 0){
            print("moving up")
            myBlocks[objectDragging].center.x = CGFloat(initPosx)
            print(abs(velocity.y))
            movingUp = true
        }


    case .changed:

        if (movingRight == true) {
            myBlocks[objectDragging].center.y = CGFloat(initPosy)
        }
        else if (movingLeft == true) {
            myBlocks[objectDragging].center.y = CGFloat(initPosy)
        }
        else if (movingDown == true) {
            myBlocks[objectDragging].center.x = CGFloat(initPosx)
        }
        else if (movingUp == true) {
            myBlocks[objectDragging].center.x = CGFloat(initPosx)
        }

    case .ended:

        movingUp = false
        movingLeft = false
        movingRight = false
        movingDown = false
```